# What's that puzzle where multiple levers change the locks' states on one door?

Tags: video-games, puzzle-identification, lights-out, locks

I have seen this one a few times in videogames and elsewhere, but I don't remember where.

You have to open one door that has several locks on it. You have a bunch of levers that when moved change the state of some of the locks (open/closed), but the catch is that some levers control the same locks and when you think you opened a lock, the next moment you might close it if you don't deduce the right combination.

What do you call this kind of puzzle? I am not sure how to design and code this one yet so I am looking for examples, references (videogames) and some help.

Comment: Hi, Pastille! Puzzling Stack Exchange is not a normal discussion forum. Questions should be solely questions, so we don't put answers in questions. Answers go in answers. To indicate that an answer is correct or that you see the question as solved, you can "accept" an answer (which you've done, yay!), See our [tour] and [help] for more information.

Comment: I understand. I thought that the question itself was not very suggestive of any relatable problem and wanted to increase the usefulness. I hope people in the future will understand this is a variant of lights out, thanks.

Comment: Been playin' dregg?

Comment: No George, should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps describe a puzzle like this as a ***Lights Out*** style puzzle. The game Lights Out consists of a grid of illuminated input buttons, with the goal being to turn all the lights off. Each button toggles multiple lights ("locks"), so that each button press can lock or unlock several elements at the same time. The goal is to find the correct sequence of inputs to unlock all the elements simultaneously.

In Lights Out, there's a clear spatial relationship between the inputs and the locks (each button toggles its own light and all adjacent lights), but you could build a Lights Out game where each button controls an arbitrary set of locks.

[Here's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/326460/how-do-i-solve-this-lights-out-style-puzzle) an example of a gaming question that references a Lights Out style puzzle where the inputs can lock or unlock multiple elements. The adjacency of the controlling and toggling elements makes this puzzle essentially a 1-D version of Lights Out.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment has opened up quite a few interesting perspective. I remember I used to play a version of Lights Out on [Nintendo DS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mqAMbGBhQw).

However the 1D version would better fit the kind of game I want to implement this in. I have found [this discussion](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/505257/multiple-switches-flipflop-lights-onoff-logic-puzz.html) on Unreal forums, and I am going to attempt something similar.

Comment: If you want to see more puzzles that are similar to Lights Out, try browsing through the questions and answers on this site tagged [[tag:lights-out]]